# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split'), how to remove error in jwt token verify

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
const jwtEmail=req.body.email.split("@")[0]

            console.log(jwtEmail)
            const token=jwt.sign({user_data:email},jwtEmail,{
              expiresIn:"24h"
            }
            )
const verifyToken=async(req,res,next)=>{
  
    try {
      const token = req.header.authorization.split("")[0];
      const user_data =await  User.findOne({auth_token:token})
      const jwtEmail = user_data.email.split("@")[0];
      const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token,jwtEmail);
      next(); 
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: "Auth failed",
        error
        
      });
    }
    
  }`
```

can not able to  verify  token, an issue in split. in error , which is showing split is undefined. how can solve issue in split. below mention my codes & issues. how can solve issue in split? here how can regenerate token from existing code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const generateToken = (email) => {
  const jwtEmail = email.split("@")[0];

  console.log(jwtEmail);

  const token = jwt.sign({ user_data: email }, 'your-secret-key', {
    expiresIn: "24h"
  });

  return token;
};

const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const user_data = await User.findOne({ auth_token: token });
    const jwtEmail = user_data.email.split("@")[0];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'your-secret-key');
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      message: "Auth failed",
      error
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Code is working Properly Thanks !!

Comment: @Shivanshusingh Glad happy to help

Comment: If the you has any such community in which the solution to the question of node react is found, then please add me

Comment: token is function block define but use in out of function

Answer (score 0):

Your error log is not saying that split is undefined, but rather that `req.header.authorization` or `req.body.email` is undefined and therefore split is not a method of that string.

Try see why the req object is not defined at the time of trying to use split.